# How to draw a plot 2d panel in eclipse (plug-in development)

Tags: plot, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a plug-in (with viewpart) within I want to draw a panel (an axis).
unfortunately I can't use Plot2DPanel from org.math.plot, the plugin doesn't accept this.
Is there a way the reach the same result in eclipse plug-in development?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it can help someone. There is a way to draw something like that:**Eclipse draw2D**

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.draw2d.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fdraw2d%2FPanel.html